# 'If we would have done what you wanted, I would have never have found them' - is this correct? (from Rick and Morty)

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Just watched Rick and Morty and in the pilot there's something like that - "if we would have done what you wanted, I would have never have found them". It sounds incorrect to me, shouldn't it be something like "I would have never found them" instead?

Comment: I wouldn't watch Rick and Morty for examples of beautiful English. The sentence is understandable. Whether it's "correct" is debatable; it could also be context-dependent: was the speaker on drugs?  Were the writers trying to be funny? Etc. It's correct as far as it's understandable.

Answer (score 1):

> if we would have done what you wanted

Could be more simply stated
as

> If we did what you wanted

You are correct about

> I would have never <s>have</s> found them

but since the plural is used in the first part, it might be better to continue with

> we would have never found them.